# cannot call a function before it is defined

Tags: python

When I run:

```
if language == "":
    language = t(30009)

# Translation util
def t(string_number):
    plugin       = xbmcaddon.Addon("plugin.video.jworg")
    return plugin.getLocalizedString(string_number)
```

I get:

> NameError: name 't' is not defined

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define the function before you use it.

```
# Translation util
def t(string_number):
    plugin       = xbmcaddon.Addon("plugin.video.jworg")
    return plugin.getLocalizedString(string_number)

if language == "":
    language = t(30009)
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to do anything. Just call it.

**Edit** You're calling it before it's defined. The definition needs to go before the call.